# Npm Error: Failed to load plugin import: Cannot find module '../docsUrl'

Tags: npm, runtime-error, npm-install, npm-scripts

Getting following error on `npm start`

```
Failed to compile.

Error in ./src/index.js
Module build failed: Error: Failed to load plugin import: Cannot find module '../docsUrl'
Referenced from: game/package.json
 @ multi main
```

Already tried to reinstall nvm, node, npm. Didn't solve my problem.
Any idea how to solve this error? I can't find any npm package on their website which is called docsUrl.

Answer (score 2):

This happens to me when I accidentally update [eslint-plugin-import](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import) from version 2.8.0 (which is default for create-react-app) to 2.9.0 .

**Solution**

1. Remove package `eslint-plugin-import` from node_modules
2. Remove package-lock.json file
3. Make sure you have `"eslint-plugin-import": "2.8.0"` in depedency section in your package.json
4. Run `npm install`
5. Everything should work now